# How to generate data randomly in database table ABAP SAP?

Tags: abap

I have this code, with it I can select table from system and dispaly its content. I want to add records for example 10 and generate random data in my table, I have to findthe data in se11 TCode. have someone an idea please? Idea, code which can I learn from, or video. I am still beginner. Thank you

```html
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report Z_THIRD_REPORT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
REPORT Z_THIRD_REPORT.


TABLES: DFIES,
  X030L.

DATA: BEGIN OF INTTAB OCCURS 100.
  INCLUDE STRUCTURE DFIES.
DATA: END OF INTTAB.


DATA: FIELD_DATA_TYPE TYPE DFIES-DATATYPE,
      NUM_RECORDS TYPE I.

*PARAMETERS: p_taname TYPE DDOBJNAME OBLIGATORY.
PARAMETERS: TABLENM TYPE dd02l-tabname OBLIGATORY,
            RECORDS TYPE I.
*FIELDNM TYPE DFIES-FIELDNAME.

  SELECT * FROM dd02l INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_tables)
     WHERE ( tabname LIKE 'Z%' OR tabname LIKE 'Y%' )
       AND as4local = 'A'
       AND tabclass IN ('TRANSP', 'INTTAB').

CALL FUNCTION 'DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET'
EXPORTING
  tabname              = TABLENM
*FIELDNAME            = FIELDNM
  LANGU                = SY-LANGU
*         LFIELDNAME           = ' '
*         ALL_TYPES            = ' '
*       IMPORTING
*         X030L_WA             = WATAB
*         DDOBJTYPE            =
*         DFIES_WA             =
*         LINES_DESCR          =
TABLES
  DFIES_TAB            = INTTAB
*         FIXED_VALUES         =
EXCEPTIONS
  NOT_FOUND            = 1
  INTERNAL_ERROR       = 2
  OTHERS               = 3.

*      if sy-subrc <> 0.
*         WRITE:/ 'Field name not found'.
*      endif.
*
*      LOOP AT INTTAB.
*         WRITE:/ INTTAB-TABNAME, INTTAB-FIELDNAME, INTTAB-FIELDTEXT, FIELD_DATA_TYPE.
*      ENDLOOP.


*START-OF-SELECTION.
*table_name = TABLENM.
*NUM_RECORDS = RECORDS.

IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  WRITE:/ 'Field name not found'.
ELSE.

  WRITE:/ 'Fields',  'Data Type'.  " Column headers
  LOOP AT INTTAB.
    FIELD_DATA_TYPE = INTTAB-DATATYPE.  " Store the data type in FIELD_DATA_TYPE.
    WRITE:/  INTTAB-FIELDNAME, FIELD_DATA_TYPE.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [abapFaker](https://github.com/se38/abapFaker) project.

> abapFaker is an ABAP package that generates fake data for you. Whether
> you need to bootstrap your database, create good-looking XML
> documents, fill-in your persistence to stress test it, or anonymize
> data taken from a production service, Faker is for you.

Comment: Hallo mkysoft, thanks for your answer. I  have soúch fast question if you can answer me will be so nice. I has already generated data. Now I want to display the new generated data in alv format. How can I do this? I thing I have to store them in an internal table first, but I could not do this.   I will leave part of code in the other comment

Comment: FORM generate_random_data
  USING
    p_fieldname TYPE DFIES-FIELDNAME
    p_datatype   TYPE DFIES-DATATYPE
    p_records    TYPE I.

  DATA: random_value TYPE STRING,
        counter      TYPE I.

  LOOP AT INTTAB WHERE FIELDNAME = p_fieldname AND DATATYPE = p_datatype.
    DO p_records TIMES.
      " Create unique values based on field name and counter
      counter = counter + 1.
      random_value = |{ p_fieldname }_{ counter }|.

      WRITE: / p_fieldname, random_value.
    ENDDO.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDFORM.

Comment: You can check here: https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM/b1c834a22d05483b8a75710743b5ff26/4ec2430b107868bae10000000a42189e.html